# Unable to update DBML: The specified module could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

Whenever I try to make use of the following LINQ to SQL functions in VS 2010 [Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel]:

[image]

I receive the following error message:

[image]

I uninstalled VS 2010 as well as VS 2010 SP1. Then I installed VS2010 & SP1 again - this did not solve the problem!

Could anyone please assist me in this matter?

Many thanks in advance! 
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an FYI: this solved my issue

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/78537f25-6c45-4b56-b476-992e7fe8b4bf